# Subseting data frame by indices (row names)

Tags: r

I have the following problem, I have original data set with 100000 rows, and when loaded into r, each row is assigned an row name, or index from 1 to 100000. Now I made many manipulations on original data, transformations, subsetting and so on, the indices remain, which is what I want, but I don't understand how to select using them. Here is an example:

```
localTrain[1:10, c("Weight", "Label")]
    Weight Label
1   0.002653311     s
2   2.233584487     b
3   2.347388944     b 
4   5.446378212     b 
6   0.083414031     b 
8   0.018636117     s 
9   5.296002985     b 
10  0.001501870     s 
12  0.307169524     b 
15  2.151198668     b
```

But how can I select by index, for example only the rows with indices 1, 6, 15, that is:

```
   Weight Label
1  0.002653311     s
6  0.083414031     b
15 2.151198668     b
```

In this way I can select rows from subset of the data and make some operations on original data but only on values with the same index or row name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need rownames with a stable definition, then you should definite the rownames.

```
rownames(localTrain) <- as.character(seq_len(nrow(localTrain)))
localTrain[c("1", "6", "15"), ]
```

Userdefined rownames are characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
localTrain [index (localTrain) %in% c(1,6,15),]
```

or:

```
localTrain [rownames(localTrain) %in% c("1", "6", "15"),]
```